# hp ilo "remote console undefined"

Tags: hp, remote-access, hp-proliant, remote, ilo

After upgrading my server (HP DL360p Gen8) to the latest ILO 4.30 I have such error

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49126809/iloUndefined.png]

What should I do and how to fix my problem? I do not have physical access to my server and so now I have no access at all (I still have ILO with no remote console)

I think probably I should use "back-up" copy of ilo if it stored on server... or should I reupload some another ILO version?

**upd** I've noticed that undefined link is "https://*****/html/undefined", i think I can try "hack" and just type direct link to "remote" page, but i do not have an address. It should be something like "https://*****/html/remote.html" Probably someone, who has access to ilo, can give me a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your browser. Flush your cache. Open the ILO again.

If that does not work, reset the ILO by going to "Diagnostics" and choose "Reset ILO".

Comment: Thanks, it seems starting from 4.30 they changed "Remote" page to "javascript" and now I have to use another browser. I can see "Remote" window now!